# How do I make this particular method compile with one argument and return void in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am required in this code to use three different types of methods other than the main. The one I am having trouble with is on line 9, where I need to make a method that has one argument and returns void. In a separate file I got it to work by having the contents of the parenthesis in the header (String[] greetings) in the body of the method, but that would not fulfill my criteria of needing an argument.

The purpose of the custom method is to make a very simple array that gives me one of the four custom messages when run. I understand that it isn't the most practical use of an array, but I need to utilize it for an assignment.

I need that array to be inside the custom method as close to how it is as possible, so my question to you is how do i make that method compile correctly?

I am aware that the code as a whole will not compile correctly in its current state, the other fixes I know how to do. I really apologize in advance for any formatting errors, This is my first ever question on this website. I worked for many many hours on this with a tutor but we ran out of time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class firstDraftFinal   {

   public static void simpleArray(String[] greetings) {

      "Welcome To CWU BANK!", "Thank you for using CWU ATM!", "Please insert DEBIT card", "We value your business!"
      };

      int i = (int)(Math.random() * greetings.length);
      System.out.println(greetings[i]);

      }
   static void printStartupMessage()  {
      System.out.println("Card accepted");
      System.out.println("Enter PIN #: ****");
      System.out.println("verifying...");
      System.out.println("PIN acccepted");
   }

   public static double getRandomBalance()   {
      Random randomNumbers = new Random();
      double randomBalance = 20.0 + (10000.0 - 20.0) * randomNumbers.nextDouble();
      randomBalance = Math.round(randomBalance * 100);
      randomBalance = randomBalance/100;
      return randomBalance;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException   {

      String[] greetings = {"Welcome To CWU BANK!", "Thank you for using CWU ATM!", "Please insert DEBIT card", "We value your business!"};

      double amountToWithdrawl;
      double saveRandomBalance;
      double remainingBalance; 

      printStartupMessage();

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner keyboardDouble = new Scanner(System.in);

      saveRandomBalance = getRandomBalance();

      System.out.println("CHECKING BALANCE**** $" + saveRandomBalance);
      System.out.println("Would you like to withdrawl from CHECKING****? Y/N");
      String proceedWithWithdrawl = keyboard.nextLine();

      while (!proceedWithWithdrawl.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !proceedWithWithdrawl.equalsIgnoreCase("n") 
         && !proceedWithWithdrawl.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !proceedWithWithdrawl.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) 
      {
         System.out.println("Invalid response. Enter [Y] or [N].");
         proceedWithWithdrawl = keyboard.next();
      } 

      switch(proceedWithWithdrawl)
      {
         case "N": 
            System.out.println("Returning card... please wait...");
            System.out.println("Card returned. Thank you for using CWU Bank!");
            break;
         case "n":
            System.out.println("Returning card... please wait...");
            System.out.println("Card returned. Thank you for using CWU Bank!");
            break;
         case "NO":
            System.out.println("Returning card... please wait...");
            System.out.println("Card returned. Thank you for using CWU Bank!");
            break;
         case "no":
            System.out.println("Returning card... please wait...");
            System.out.println("Card returned. Thank you for using CWU Bank!");
            break;
         case "No":
            System.out.println("Returning card... please wait...");
            System.out.println("Card returned. Thank you for using CWU Bank!");
            break;
         case "Y":  
            System.out.println("Enter amount to withdrawl: ");
            amountToWithdrawl = keyboardDouble.nextDouble();
            remainingBalance = saveRandomBalance - amountToWithdrawl;
            remainingBalance = Math.round(remainingBalance * 100);
            remainingBalance = remainingBalance/100;

            if (amountToWithdrawl % 20 == 0 && amountToWithdrawl <= saveRandomBalance)
            {

                  System.out.println("Dispensing...");
                  System.out.println("ACCOUNT BALANCE: $" + remainingBalance);
                  System.out.println("$" + amountToWithdrawl + " has been withdrawn from CHECKING****");
                  System.out.println("Returning card... please wait...");
                  System.out.println("Card returned. Thank you for using CWU Bank!");
                  CallDollarBill.dollarBill();
                  break;
             }
             else if (amountToWithdrawl > saveRandomBalance)
             {
                  System.out.println("Insufficient Balance.");
                  break;
             }
         } 
      }
}
```

Any help or examples are HIGHLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have some code out of your method..

```
int i = (int)(Math.random() * greetings.length);
System.out.println(greetings[i]);
```

solution... the 'greetings.length' cant be reach outside the method.

```
public static void simpleArray(String[] greetings) {

              String str = "Welcome To CWU BANK!", "Thank you for using CWU ATM!", "Please insert DEBIT card", "We value your business!";

              int i = (int)(Math.random() * greetings.length);
              System.out.println(greetings[i]);
              }
          }
```

Comment: cant believe I made such a dumb mistake thank you... now, knowing that I cant encase a string in { }, why might it be saying "identifier expected" between the comma after "welcome to CWU BANK!", and "Thank you for using CWU ATM!"? im looking through my book trying to figure out how to get it to accept String st as four different outputs?

Comment: Is it a whole sentence (String) or is it a array? :) you welcome brow, I do these mistakes all the time too haha

Comment: when you use the comma after the (") tag java thinks you starts a new variable. you can make a String[] like this...

Comment: It was an array, and with your help I think i just about got it! it compiles so I think it accepts the array, now I just  need to play around with the int i statements to make it actually print one to screen. Thanks you so much Marc! this has been giving me headaches for days

Comment: Haha I spend 2 days almost troughing my laptop out the window for a wrong " tag haha :P... remember to hit the answer button. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] strArr = {"Welcome To CWU BANK!", "Thank you for using CWU ATM!", "Please insert DEBIT card", "We value your business!"};
```